# metamask custom rpc problem

Tags: metamask

I use metamask custom RPC and set it to be http://myip:8545, and it looks like keep trying connecting, but always not finish, actually I am using private ethereum network, whether I must mine on my private network to make the metamask ok?

Comment: write down the command you used to run the node along with the question

Comment: I just init and  start a private geth node on 8545 on a vps, and then I try to input htttp://theIP:8545 on custom RPC in metamask, it will always run and wait.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Genache installed? If not, You have to have a local instance of the blockchain running on your computer in order to use the custom RPC.

If you do have Genache installed then copy the data called RPC server at the top of the genache client and use it as your custom RPC. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but ganache server is a testing node so how can I copy the data to it? also I think the block/per min is different from the real node. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Validate if you have used the below RPC parameters in your geth command.
*--rpc --port "30303" --rpcport "8545"*

Comment: do u have to do this when u instantiate the chain or when u start the chain?